# Dynamically add and close DIV to group of 3 cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 and receive lines of data like below from the DB/backend. I'm wondering if there's a way to **dynamically** wrap each group of 3 with `<div class="row">...</div>` for big screen size (>992), and wrap each group of 2 with the same `<div class="row">...</div>` for smaller screen size.

**What received**

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
```

**Desired Ouput for Big Screen (>=992)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
</div>
```

**Desired Ouput for Smaller Screen (<992)**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to slice the columns you want to display
- [`.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrap the sliced columns
- [`.unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to remove any previous wrapper

**Note:** Run snippet in *"Full page"* mode.

```js
function columnsWrapper(cols) {
  let $cardHolders = $('.cardHolder').unwrap('.row');

  // wrap
  for (let i = 0; i < $cardHolders.length; i += cols) {
    let $slice = $cardHolders.slice(i, i + cols);
    $slice.wrapAll('<div class="row" />')
  }
}

function displayColumns() {
  if ($(window).width() > 992) {
    columnsWrapper(3);
  } else {
    columnsWrapper(2);
  }
}

displayColumns();
$(window).resize(() => displayColumns());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">4</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">5</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">6</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">7</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">8</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 cardHolder">9</div>
</div>
```